# Add a page browser to front-end extension

Tags: php, typo3

Is it possible to add a page browser (browse_links) like this to a front end extension?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Add the 'suggest' wizzard in the TCA for that field:

```
'yourlink' => array (
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:yourextension/locallang_general.xml:yourlink',
    'config' => array (
        'type' => 'group',
        'internal_type' => 'db',
        'allowed' => 'pages',
        'size' => '1',
        'maxitems' => '1',
        'minitems' => '0',
        'show_thumbs' => '1',
        'wizards' => array(
            'suggest' => array(
                'type' => 'suggest',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: The problem is that the form is in front end. Generated by my extension. So I need some php code that generates the browser.